# An expanding, sliding charged tube's self-imposed electromagnetic induction

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, momentum, inertia

If I have a simple cylindrical electrically-insulating tube possessing a net electrostatic charge and allow the tube to slide parallel to the tube's axis, that tube will possess electric currents parallel to that axis, generating magnetic fields. The direction of the magnetic fields would point one way or the other, depending on which direction is it allowed to slide.

I could also boost my observer's frame parallel to the tube to observe circular magnetic fields oriented one way or the other.

For small changes in our observer's velocity, our geometry-dependent "self-inductance" of the tube remains essentially the same, and yet small changes in our observer's velocity may be quite adequate to observe "reversed" magnetic fields. It would therefore follow that the axial electric fields that the tube generates upon itself as it simultaneously expands and translates would be non-zero.

Obviously, the charged tube with expanding radius should not self-accelerate. Therefore, these axial electric fields imposed by the expanding tube on itself, which attempt to preserve the "current" of the tube, must somehow fail to produce an observable acceleration. In other words, even in the absence of other forces, the Lorentz force on a charge does not equal the mass of the charge times its coordinate acceleration - there is a difference. .....Strangely enough, a negative change of (mostly electric) potential energy associated with the expanding tube appears to have an opposite effect on this difference (opposed to its motion) when compared to what a negative change in kinetic energy does to this difference (favoring its motion). Why should that be?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the loss in potential energy results in a force which opposes the motion? 
This would mean both potential and kinetic energy would be decreasing, so the total energy in the EM fields would have to be increasing rapidly. However, for expanding charge/currents the energy in the EM fields typically decreases (because for the limit where the charge/current in infinitely dense, the integral s of E^2  and B^2  diverge). Even though the current is faster, the corresponding contribution to the B field is orders of magnitude less than the strength of the E field.

Also, the example below suggests that the net force on the tube of charges is in the same direction as the motion.

[image: From my OneNote notebook]

Comment: If I took two parallel currents and tried to force them apart, the electric field would try to sustain them. So a positively charged tube expanding and moving along the x-axis in the +x direction generates interior and surface electric fields in the +x direction. However, the end result cannot be self-acceleration. The compensating term should therefore point in the -x direction. In the problem of accelerating a mass close to the speed of light, we see such an opposing term due to the increase of kinetic energy, rather than the decrease of potential energy we see here.